# Combining two tables and adding the quantities

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have 2 tables

warehouse_1

```
item  qty 
--------
3001   1
3003   3
3004   1
3006   2
```

warehouse_2

```
item   qty
----------
3001    2
3002    3
3006    3
3008    6
```

I want to union these two tables into a third and add the quantities of the same items like this

warehouse_3

```
item    qty
-----------
3001     3
3002     3
3003     3
3004     1
3006     5
3008     6
```

How can I achieve this with SQL Server?

Comment: By the way which SQL? (SQL Server, MySQL etc..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using `UNION`. First you have to union all data (of both table) and using sub-query you can group using `GROUP BY` and add total using `SUM` function.

```
SELECT Item, SUM(qty) as Qty FROM
(
   SELECT Item, qty FROM warehouse_1
   UNION
   SELECT Item, qty FROM warehouse_2
) as a
GROUP BY item;
```

See more about `UNION`:

- [SQL Server: UNION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)
- [MySQL: UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

See more about `GROUP BY` clause: (You can also find about `SUM` there.)

- [SQL Server: GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
- [MySQL: GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for all except for one item oddly so I had to use UNION ALL and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select item,sum(qty) from(
    select item, Qty from warehouse_1 
    UNION
    select item, Qty from warehouse_2
)x
group by item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW warehouse_3 as 
    SELECT coalesce(w1.item,w2.item) as item, w1.qty+w2.qty as qty
    FROM warehouse_1 as w1
    OUTER JOIN warehouse_2 as w2
    ON w1.item = w2.item;
```

Assuming that **item** is unique. **coalesce** is **nvl** in some databases.
Then you can just call:

```
select * from warehouse_3;
```

and it will return the sum.

Also if you change some of the quantities in W1 or W2 it will be automatically corrected in W3

Comment: This wouldn't show items which only exist in one of the two warehouses.  You'd need a full outer join for that...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT item , SUM(qty)
FROM (
   SELECT item, qty
   FROM warehouse_1
   UNION
   SELECT item, qty
   FROM warehouse_2
) AS U GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create table tbl1(item int,qty int)
INSERT INTO tbl1
VALUES(3001,1),(3003,3),(3004,1),(3006,2)

create table tbl2(item int,qty int)
INSERT INTO tbl2
VALUES(3001,2),(3002,3),(3006,3),(3008,6)


select isnull(t1.item,t2.item) as item,isnull(t1.qty,0)+isnull(t2.qty,0) as qty from tbl1 t1 full outer join tbl2 t2 on t1.item =t2.item 
order by 1
```